# Python, finding the max value of an array above a specific value and it's index

Tags: python, indexing, max

New to python, I need to find the maximum value of an array above a lower bound,
example [1,2,3,4,5 6] find max value above 3 and what's it index position. In reality, I have one column with wavelength/energy(eV) and another (several columns) with intensity and I am trying to figure out what is the maximum intensity and it wavelength position, ignoring the laser peak which is a certain wavelength below the true data.

I tried something like this

```
df=pandas read file ['....']

column_names = ['a','b',....]

def find_max(x, y, xMax):
    return np.max(y[x < xMax])

xMax = 1.9

for i in range(len(column_names)):
    max_int_val = find_max(df['eV'], df[column_names[i]], xMax)
    max_wav_index = df[column_names[i]].idxmax(max_int_val)
    max_wav_val = df["Wavelength"].iloc[max_wav_index]
    max_eV_val = df["eV"].iloc[max_wav_index]
```

yet the max_int_val seems to be correct but the max_wav_index, max_wav_val and max_eV_val appear to be wrong.

I believe what is happening is that the index is using the entire column and not the truncated one when finding the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find by:

- Finding list of indexes in sequence which are above threshold
- Finding max of values in these indexes

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def find_max(a, lower_bound):
    ' Finds max above threshold '
    
    # Find indexes which are above threshold
    valid_idx = np.where(a >= lower_bound)[0]
    
    if valid_idx.size > 0:
        # Find maximum from these indexes
        max_idx = valid_idx[a[valid_idx].argmax()]
        return max_idx, a[max_idx]     # return index and max value
```

**Test**

```
data = [(1, 1), (2, 0), (10, 2), (5, 0)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns  = ['a','b'])
print("DataFrame\n", df)
print()

# Find max in each column of DataFrame above lower bound
lower_bound = 8
for (column_name, column_data) in df.iteritems():
    found_max = find_max(column_data, lower_bound)
    if found_max:
        print(f'Column {column_name}: max index {found_max[0]}, max_value: {found_max[1]}')
    else:
        print(f'Column {column_name}: No max found')
```

**Output**

```
DataFrame
     a  b
0   1  1
1   2  0
2  10  2
3   5  0

Column a: max index 2, max_value: 10
Column b: No max found
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your issue but i've came up with this

```
def findMax(tab,maxColumn,minimum): #maxColumn is the column you want to use,intensity in your case
    maximum=minimum
    index=-1#if it's still -1 no element was found
    for i in range(0, len(tab[maxColumn])):
        if tab[maxColumn]>maximum :
            maximum=tab[maxColumn]
            index=maxColumn
    return(maximum, index)

#then you can use index to get the wavelength with something like that : tab[wavelengthColumn][index]
```

if you have multiple intensity columns you can call this function for each and buil an array with the results that you will send again to this function

Something like that :

```
array=[........]
intensityColumns=1
maximums=[[][]]
for i in range (0,intensityColumns):
    maximum,index=findMax(array,FIRST_INTENSITY_COLUMN+i,MINIMUM)#here I suppose every intensity column is following the first one
    maximums[0].append(array[wavelengthColumn][index])
    maximums[1].append(maximum)
resultMax,resultIndex=findMax(maximums,1,MINIMUM)
```